# PHPCS result parsing stopped working in NetBeans 8.0.2 (Inspector: Unknown items)

Tags: php, netbeans, phpcs

I have NetBeans 8.0.2 on Linux Mint 17.2 Rafaela x86_64.

Installed this PHP Code Sniffer:
PHP_CodeSniffer version 2.3.4 (stable) by Squiz (http://www.squiz.net)

The results used to be parsed fine in NetBeans for a while so that they were usable.

Don't know what happened but tha parsing stopped working so I do get the PHPCS output but don't get the results in the Inspector window.

When I click the Categorize button, I get a bunch of "Unknown" items (see the image).

How do I get this working?

[image: The NetBeans Inspector window]

Answer (score 0):

Try to show result of phpcs in Windows->Action Items

And you've to Source->Inspect->codeSniffer after make changes in file

You should also check Tools->Options

[image: You should also check Tools->Options]

It's a better way to customize phpcs standards This Extras you can find...

[image: It's a better way to customize phpcs standards This Extras you can find...]

Using this, we don't need to create custom ruleset file.